# My Search Service only search the home pages for my enterprise wiki site

Tags: search, search-results, search-scope, enterprise-search

I have an enterprise wiki site collection containing 5 sub sites, currently the search service will display results from the site collection home page and from the home pages for the five sub sites, but if I have any page other than the home page, then the search will not display this page even if it contains the enter search text.
My current search settings look as follow:-

[image]

Can anyone advice what might be the problem?
Thanks

Comment: Does all your content get crawled? Have you provided a search center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have stopped all the current crawls , then i re-index my sites, i run full crawl , and this solve the problem ..

Answer (score 0):

Try to use both http and https in the "start addresses".  For example:

`http://mysharepointysite.com`
`https://mysharepointysite.com`

Comment: but i do not have a https version ..